# react highlight searched word issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try to highlight the word that is found in DIV , it does find the word, but it removes the some words at the same time, for example, when I search "a", it highlights "a" but it also removes the words "this is". I have attached my code in my post. Is it possible to fix it?

```html
<div id="app2">&nbsp;</div>
<script type="text/babel">
class MyApp extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            inputValue: "",
            fields: [<Ta />]
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        let object = this.refs.Progress1;
        let fields = this.state.fields;

        let searchBarText = e.target.value;
        let divText = object.textContent;
        let idx = divText.indexOf(searchBarText);
        if (idx >= 0) {
            let newText = [
                divText.substring(0, searchBarText),
                <strong>{divText.substring(idx, idx + searchBarText.length)}</strong>,
                divText.substring(idx + searchBarText.length)
            ];
            this.setState({ inputValue: searchBarText, fields: newText });
        } else {
            this.setState({ inputValue: searchBarText, fields: fields });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                className="input"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                placeholder="Search..."
            />
            <p ref="Progress1" id="try">
                <p>{this.state.fields}</p>
            </p>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

class Ta extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <p id="Progress1">this is a dog</p>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app2"));

</script>
<style>
    strong
    {
        color:red;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just missed a small detail:

replace:

```
let newText = [divText.substring(0, searchBarText),
                <strong>{divText.substring(idx, idx + searchBarText.length)}</strong>, divText.substring(idx + searchBarText.length)];
```

to be:

```
let newText = [divText.substring(0, idx),
                <strong>{divText.substring(idx, idx + searchBarText.length)}</strong>, divText.substring(idx + searchBarText.length)];
```